# How do i install intelliJ on Freya

Tags: jdk

I've downloaded *Intellij ultimate version* and I am trying to open `idea.sh` but it tells me this:

> "JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath. Please
>    ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE."

I don't know what to do, can anybody help? I've searched in Google but couldn't find anything.

all I know is that I have jdk because when I use `java -version` it tells me something, but I can't locate the path or somethings wrong

`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

this happened after I've installed `java-7-openjdk` before that I had `java-9-oracle` and I thought it was jdk but there were still problems

I've tried without sudo and everythings seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't have de JDK, only the JRE. Try run this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

The `java` you see on `java -version` is installed via the openjdk-*-jre package and it's able to run java applications. But to develop java (and run most of java IDEs) you need the openjdk-*-jdk packages.

If you're still having trouble, try this links:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/122133/tools-jar-is-not-in-idea-classpath

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992038/intellij-cant-find-tools-jar-without-sudo

Comment: i have that and echo $JAVA_HOME returns:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/

Comment: That's strange. I have a recently installed Freya. I just installed the openjdk-7-jdk and set the JAVA_HOME to the same folder as yours. Downloaded the IDEA Community Edition 14 and all worked fine.

Try `apt-get purge` the openjdk packages and reinstall them. Also, see if your previous installation from oracle have been completed removed as it may have conflicting configs with openjdk.